# Maven TestNG project, Replace value in properties file with a Maven command line argument

Tags: java, maven, properties-file

I have a Maven TestNG project, that has a properties file located in src/test/resources. I wanted to parameterize certain values in the properties file such that they come from the Maven command line arguments (i,e mvn clean test -U -DpropertyName=propertyVal, where "${propertyName}" exists in the properties file).

What changes do I need to make in the pom.xml file to accomplish this?

UPDATE:

Adding the pom.xml so people can see what I am working with.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Test_Automation</groupId>
<artifactId>TA_ID</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>T_QE</name>
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <maven-surefire-version>2.19.1</maven-surefire-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <src.dir>src/main/java</src.dir>
    <test.dir>src/test/java</test.dir>
    <test.resources>src/test/resources</test.resources>
</properties>
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${test.resources}</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <sourceDirectory>${src.dir}</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>target/test-classes/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <propertyName>${propertyName}</propertyName>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

UPDATE #2:
The property file (located at src/test/resources/configuration.properties) contents are below:

```
api.username=${propertyName}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing called filtering - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html.

Basically you add this to your build:

```
  <build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
  </build>
```

Then inside your profile you would do:

```
  <profile>
      <id>myprofile</id>
      ...
      <properties>
        <propertyName>${propertyName}</propertyName>
      </properties>
    </profile>
```

Assuming in your .properties file you have:

```
myProperty = ${propertyName}
```

Try it out.

**Update**

This plugin has to be in your pom:

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
```

And you should add this to your maven execution command:

```
mvn resources:testResources
```

Comment: This didnt work. The "${propertyName}" in the properties file did not get replaced once I ran the command mentioned in the original question.

Comment: it should be testResources in the build. My bad. Try it now

Comment: Tried again, and it still didnt work. I removed the "resources" tag from pom as well.

Comment: Didnt work. I made the updates as you have given. The new maven command is "mvn clean test -U resources:testResources -DpropertyName=propertyVal". The property value did not change in the properties file.

Comment: OK let me do some more tests

Comment: Did some more tests and it works perfectly. Please add your properties file.. or at least the entry that we are dealing with here

Comment: Added the .properties contents as requested.

Comment: Do you check your file in: /target/test-classes/configuration.properties ?

Comment: Do you have this in your build logs: [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ unit-testing ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources ?

Comment: Yes. Looks like...... [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-cli) @ TA_ID ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 9 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ TA_ID ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/user/testproj/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ TA_ID ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/user/testproj/src/main/resources
[INFO]

Comment: Ok lets dig deeper. Run mvn with -X option, place the output in Dropbox or somewhere and give me the link

Comment: [DEBUG] Copying file config.properties
[DEBUG] file config.properties has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] filtering /Users/user/testproj/src/test/resources/config.properties to /Users/user/testproj/target/test-classes/config.properties             Filtering is happening for sure

Comment: But the command line argument is still not replacing the one in the properties file. So in the tests that use the property, the value is still "${propertyName}" instead of "propertyVal".

Comment: Ok, but is actual file in target directory updated? MAybe its a problem in your test code alone

Comment: I did a test once more on exactly your config.. char to char.. and it works. Im afraid my knowledge ends here. Hope my tips were helpful in some way anyway.